# Qt: compilation issue with minGW

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, mingw

I got a Qt environment that I need to compile.
But when compiling, I get the following messages:

```
g++ -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\Prog.exe object_script.Prog.Release -L"c:\DevProgs\Qt\4.8.6\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmain build\objects\myapp_res.o -LC:/Windows/System32 -lftd2xx -LC:/qwt-6.0.1/lib -lqwt -lQtSql4 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4 
[MGWPATH]/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `_imp__Sleep@4'
[MGWPATH]/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `_imp__SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4'
Makefile.Release:303: recipe for target 'release\Prog.exe' failed
[MGWPATH]/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `_set_invalid_parameter_handler'
[MGWPATH]/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x475): undefined reference to `_imp__GetStartupInfoA@4'
[MGWPATH]/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: [MGWPATH]/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.CRT$XCAA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

where `[MGWPATH]` is `C:/DevProgs/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../..`

I sucessfully ran small demos of Qt4.8.6 alone and one with Qwt.

The only doubt I have is regarding the ftd2xx lib.
But, I think it is linked properly because I am able to produce errors of undefined function if I don't link the DLL.

The error message is not clear to me. So, I have absolutely no idea where to look from here!

Could someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Try to add -lkernel32 (for Windows) since SetUnhandledExceptionFilter and GetStartupInfo are from kernel32 library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my issue!

Comment: Do you have exactly the same errors?

Comment: Yes I get exactly the same errors with command: g++ -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\Prog.exe object_script.Prog.Release  -L"c:\DevProgs\Qt\4.8.6\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmain build\objects\myapp_res.o -LC:/Windows/System32 -lftd2xx ***-LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32*** -LC:/qwt-6.0.1/lib -lqwt -lQtSql4 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4

Comment: **-LC:/Windows/System32** is not the path where Win lib files are stored. It should be something like `[MGWPATH]\i686-w64-mingw32\lib`.

Comment: You can try to remove -LC:/Windows/System32 and let the linker find proper version of kernel32 itself.

Comment: I tried this too, but it doesn't change anything. Thanks for the advice anyway!

Comment: I finally solved my problem. It was caused by the version of the DLL. I found the version that worked with pre-existing project. Thanks for your help.